# "Horicontal" etymology—mistaken foreign spelling of horizontal?

Tags: etymology

I came across the word "horicontal" in a technical paper. The context made it clear that its meaning was effectively identical to "horizontal". I looked into it, suspecting a misspelling. I found enough instances of the word in published works that I now think it is more than a mere typo.

It seems to me that I saw "horicontal" used with disproportionately high frequency in technical publications, and in publications with at least one (usually more) German authors.

I'd like to know the etymology of "horicontal"—how did this spelling originate? Does it appear as a translation in foreign dictionaries? I could not find any examples of such.

Here are some examples of "horicontal" in published work:

- https://books.google.com/books?id=sj_Ry-MgBQQC&pg=PA1468&dq=horicontal
- https://books.google.com/books?id=ZuvrCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA169&dq=horicontal

And a slide originally from the 1918 "Gray's Anatomy of the Human Body", whose Wikipedia Commons file description by two Germans uses the word "horicontal" while the file name uses "horiconatal" which is almost certainly a typo (natal or conatal make no sense in context):

- https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Telencephalon-Horiconatal.jpg

Comment: There are actually quite a few examples of its usage, https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=horicontal&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Choricontal%3B%2Cc0 -

Comment: At first I thought that it be related to the fact that the German QWERTZ keyboard is different from the English  QWERTY. That's true but it doesn't provide the answer. Also the German word for horizontal is horizontal. Another possible reason is imitation. Just as incorrect song lyrics propagate across the web, maybe so has this spelling. I'm not convinced by any of these. Maybe it would be best to contact one of the authors and ask.

Comment: @Josh61: There are significantly more instances of [_horixontal_ than of _horicontal_](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=horicontal%2Chorixontal&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=0&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Choricontal%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chorixontal%3B%2Cc0), which is not surprising given that X is between Z and C on a standard QWERTY keyboard; but the vast majority of Google Books search result matches for either term are simply OCR misreadings of _horizontal_, as choster points out in an answer below. There is no entry for either spelling in the big OED.

Comment: A corruption of horiçontal is also possible.

Comment: Whatever it is, it's a mistake. Sometimes there really are mistakes. People don't mean everything that they say.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems to be based on speculation that the word 'horicontal' might be something more than a keyboard typo or an OCR error—but without pointing to any source that offers substantive or theoretical support for that speculation.

Comment: I think this is it: https://german.stackexchange.com/a/24920/46368

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the basic Ngram of [*horicontal* vs. *horizontal*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=horicontal%2Chorizontal&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3), the former has a 2008 prevalence of .0000000086% and the latter of .0019994350%; in other words, *horizontal* is 232,492 times more common.

*Horizontol* comes in at .0000000270%, [more than three times as common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=horizontol%2Choricontal%2Chorixontal%2Chorisontal&year_start=1950&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3). But Google Books is chock full of OCR errors, and we could write that off to the similarity of *o* and *a* glyphs in some typefaces, especially when ink may be faded or worn. That doesn't explain *horixontal*, however, with a prevalence of .0000000418%.

What does explain it is that on an English QWERTY keyboard, *Z*, *X*, and *C* are all situated at the far left of the bottom row, and while the first two are relatively rare (and difficult to reach), *C* is fairly common, and a typist's muscle memory may punch the wrong key out of habit.

I don't see real evidence that the typos are more common among German authors. On German QWERTZU keyboards, the positions of *Y* and *Z* are switched compared to the QWERTY, so perhaps someone accustomed to a QWERTY keyboard typing on a QWERTZU keyboard would hit *C* or *X* instead of *Z* more often— but then we'd expect at least a few appearances of *horiyontal*, of which Google Books has none.

Comment: Thank you for mentioning the possibility of automatic character recognition errors. I'm comfortable accepting that as the correct explanation. Typos make less sense when they are seen several times in close proximity in the same documents. @choster

Comment: I'm vaguely recalling that in some European languages the character Z (at least in upper case) tends to be barred, similar to the number 7.  This could somehow figure into the confusion.

Answer (score 4):

My Google-fu is not great, but the *only* place I've found it on the internet in a non-scanned format is this very question. It occasionally comes up from 1807 on, but half of the time, when I click on the site, the word in the book is actually [**hori-zontal**](https://books.google.com/books?id=juZhAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA32&dq=%22horicontal%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CE4Q6AEwCGoVChMI8a6606GVxwIVgT8-Ch3gUgrB#v=onepage&q=%22horicontal%22&f=false).

[image]

Other paces, the *z* is [smudged](https://books.google.com/books?id=hn8AAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA304&dq=%22horicontal%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CD0Q6AEwBWoVChMI8a6606GVxwIVgT8-Ch3gUgrB#v=onepage&q=%22horicontal%22&f=false) or [incomplete](https://books.google.com/books?id=nqlAAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA2615&dq=%22horicontal%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CEMQ6AEwBmoVChMI8a6606GVxwIVgT8-Ch3gUgrB#v=onepage&q=%22horicontal%22&f=false):

[image]

[image]

I can't say I know enough about scanning mistakes, but I can see why it might be read as a "c".

Comment: Yes, I have seen a fair number of similar scanning mistakes when searching for other terms.